# вырезать на основе QPainterPath

Tags: c++, qt

в QPixmap имеется метод copy который принимает QRect. можно вырезать часть изображения на основе QPainterPath ?

Comment: Что должно быть результатом операции вырезания

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот так например:

```
QPixmap copyPath(const QPixmap & src, const QPainterPath & area)
{
     QPixmap result(src.size());

     QPainter canvas(&result);
     canvas.setClipPath(area);
     canvas.drawPixmap(0,0,src);

     return result;
}
```